# sharepoint 2010 find in Documen set allowed content types

Tags: sharepoint

How to find all content type in document set, and escpecially how to selected allowable content types

Answer (score 1):

```
SPDocumentLibrary oDocumentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)list;
SPContentTypeCollection typecollection = oDocumentLibrary.ContentTypes;
string a = null;
foreach (SPContentType types in typecollection)
{
    a = types.Parent.Id.ToString();
    ArrayList masyvas = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList masyvas22 = new ArrayList();
    if (a.Contains("0x0120D520"))  //DocumentSeto id
    {
        masyvas22.Add(types); //dadeta
        masyvas.Add(types.Id);
        //tikrint type id bus reikalinga kuriant document seta  
        DocumentSetTemplate temp = DocumentSetTemplate.GetDocumentSetTemplate(types);
        AllowedContentTypeCollection allowedcontenttype = temp.AllowedContentTypes;
        String g = null;
        foreach (SPContentTypeId ss in allowedcontenttype)
        {
// ...
```